# Controlling a geographically mobile Pi 3 (using iPhone 6S)

Tags: pi-3, bluetooth, remote, connection

I've had a look around and I can't find anyone with a similar setup to what I'm looking for, maybe someone here can help?

I want a Pi3 that I can carry with me and control from my phone (terminal interface only) for mobile network diagnostics, access to SSH servers etc. Because it's coming with me SSH via a Dyn-DNS doesn't seem to be an option, due to relocation and Wi-Fi passwords etc. Ideally I want it to operate in environments without a network connection. I'd like the Pi to run on Kali, but any distro is fine!

My perfect scenario would be using the bluetooth to connect to the PI from my phone, leaving my phone able to connect to the Wi-Fi wherever I am.

Any ideas?

Comment: Little tricky to diagnose without knowing the capabilities of your phone. It might be helpful if you added a make/model number to your question. If I understand your question correctly, it sounds like you could probably just connect the Pi to the phone's mobile WiFi hotspot (if it has one).

Comment: and connect to the pi using SSH on 192.168 etc etc ?

Comment: That's how I do it. I'm afraid I'm none too sharp on Apple's product line. On my Android devices I use an app called [ConnectBot](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.connectbot&hl=en_GB) for SSH'ing into other things. I'm pretty sure there's an [equivalent option for iOS](http://ioshacker.com/apps/best-terminal-ssh-clients-for-ios). It's not quite the Bluetooth you were looking for, but would that approach (WiFi hotspot/iOS app for SSH) satisfy your question requirements?

Comment: Only one way to know, I'll test it when I get a pi 3. But ideally I'd still like a Bluetooth option if possible.

Answer (score 0):

The Pi3 only has support for HID and Audio services, so you can **NOT** use Bluetooth. "Bluetooth support is limited at this stage; you can pair with pretty much anything, but you can only usefully connect to devices which support either the Human Interface Device or Audio Sink services – in other words, mice, keyboards and other UI devices, and speakers and headsets." https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/another-update-raspbian/

Answer (score 0):

You will need a separate BLE serial interface module. iPhone usually can with with those without MFi licensing, and you can establish connection between iPhone and API that way. Keep in mind that this does means that you have to write your own interfacing app for the phone.

An alternative is to add a second Wi-Fi module on the Pi, for example a RTL8188CUS based one. This gives you a local Wi-Fi access point your iPhone can join, and SSH protocol can run on top of.